# Find all pairs of consecutive numbers in array

Tags: arrays, matlab

How would you find all pairs of consecutive numbers in an array with MATLAB?
For example:

```
A = [1 2 3 4];
B = desiredFunction(A)  % B = [1 2;2 3;3 4]
```

Obviously, I could loop through the array using `for` but I would assume that there is a more elegant method of doing this. Maybe even some variant of reshape.

Oh, A in my scenario will always be sorted but does not have to fullfil all(diff(A) == 1). If the sorting of A helps, two solutions would be welcome (one for always sorted A, and one general solution).

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
B = [A(1:end-1)',A(2:end)'];
```

Comment: true, very easy. Should have thought of that :)

Answer (score 1):

I interpret you mean consecutive *positions*, and you want pairs without repetitions.

[`unique`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) does this easily:

```
B = unique([A(1:end-1).' A(2:end).'], 'rows');
```

You could also use [`sparse`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html), which will give you the number of times each pair occurs:

```
>> A = [1 2 3 4 3 4]; %// note: [3 4] appears twice
>> sparse(A(1:end-1), A(2:end), 1)
ans =
   (1,2)        1
   (2,3)        1
   (4,3)        1
   (3,4)        2
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to interpret "conescutive numbers" in the question, but I think you should add `idx = find(diff(A) == 1); result = B(idx,:)`.

Comment: I interpret "consecutive _positions_", not "consecutive _values_"

Comment: I mean consecutive values. So B for A = [10 50 5] would be B = [10 50; 50 5], actually with repetition. So unique for my purpose is not necessary